# pROC plot as object?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, roc, proc-r-package

I would like to construct a rPOC plot OBJECT that I can pass to a function and plot later.  In the example below (taken from [here](http://web.expasy.org/pROC/screenshots.html)), I can certainly plot my roc curve. But I would like to create a plot OBJECT (say by defining g <- and later plotting it with plot(g)).  It seems that the plot of ciobj, ci functions below will add to the original plot, but I can't make an OBJECT assembling these layers together.  I have tried the 'add' argument, and creating new plot objects with the return values of these plot functions.

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
rocobj <- plot.roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b,  main="Confidence intervals", percent=TRUE,  ci=TRUE,  print.auc=TRUE)
ciobj <- ci.se(rocobj, specificities=seq(0, 100, 5))
plot(ciobj, type="shape", col="#1c61b6AA") 
plot(ci(rocobj, of="thresholds", thresholds="best"))
```

Comment: You really can't. These function use base graphics which work by drawing directly to the graphics device. There is no object created like when working with lattice or ggplot graphics. Why do you think you need an object? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: so as to keep my code as DRY as possible.  I have the need for plotting different roc curves (among others) across different documents that have the potential to change a lot.  I was just creating a general plot functions that I can easily use when needed so I don't have to repeat similar code many times in a single file and to avoid identical code across multiple documents (knitr document, 'ReporteRs' presentation, etc)

Comment: Then just wrap your commands in a function you can call when you need to plot the data. Rather than storing "plot objects", you can store "plotting functions."

Comment: There's a recently introduced package by Paul Murrell (the author of the grid pkg) that might do something like this. IIRC, the name of the pkg is gridSVG and it makes an attempt to construct an SVG file from a base graphics call. And then (I think) you can then import that file to do further manipulations.

Comment: MrFlick: Thanks. I guess the problem is that the ReporteRs package that adds plots (addImage in my case), doesn't catch the 'layers' that I add to the plot (the last two plot statments above).  It could be either something that I'm doing wrong or the package itself, but even though it plots fine in rstudio, i lose these layers.  But maybe I'll just have to dig deeper into that package
BondedDust: thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: @BondedDust although related to gridSVG (same author), the package you refer to is probably [gridGraphics (pdf link)](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/murrell.pdf), and doesn't deal with SVG directly, but rather attempts to reproduce the current graphics scene as a grid object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrFlick mentioned you can pass functions instead of object. Alternatively you can pass unevaluated function calls, and evaluate them within your function. For instance:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)


plot1 <- quote(plot(rocobj, main="Confidence intervals", print.auc=TRUE))
plot2 <- quote(plot(ci.se(rocobj, specificities=seq(0, 100, 5)), type="shape", col="#1c61b6AA"))
plot3 <- quote(plot(ci(rocobj, of="thresholds", thresholds="best")))

doplots <- function(rocobj, calls) {
  for (call in calls) {
    eval(call)
  }
  invisible(rocobj)
}

roc1 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, percent = TRUE)
doplots(roc1, list(plot1, plot2, plot3))

roc2 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns, percent = TRUE)
doplots(roc2, list(plot1, plot3))
```

There is no limit to what you can do, except your patience with R's evaluation rules.

Comment: Thanks for the response Calimo. The issue is that I wanted a function that would return 2 things: a plot object and a table (because to set up plot1,2,3 above there is some modeling which returns additional output I want to return from the function.)  Is it possible to modify your code so I have a function that I can use to return a 1) function to pass to a ReporteRs function (addPlot(...FUN =...), and 2) a table with data in it to pass to addFlexTable()?  I know now I can't pass a plot object, but maybe a list? But I'm not sure how to get a function in a list or if it's even possible.

Comment: If your function returns multiple things they must be wrapped in a list. That list can contain anything, calls, roc objects, tables, etc, and you can code the receiving function to accept anything. But that is beyond the scope of this very question that is about passing "plot objects" - my solution to this being calls.

Comment: Ok I found out how to do it, thanks for your help.  For anyone else: I didn't need to nest a function or anything like that.  I just used the three plot functions above (without 'quote') in a function and then passed an roc 'object' to it from the other function which did the analysis.  I used this plot function for the plot generation, and generated the roc from the other function in which i passed any other information as a list.